# Swapping Classes of Many Items in Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to swap the classes of items in a time interval for many elements. For instance, 5 elements will be showed up initialy, the rest 5 elements will be hidden. After 10 seconds, the hidden 5 will be shown up and the initialy showned elements will be hidden. After 10 seconds again the same as in the initial makeup and so on.

But i got stuck with the logic of mine as within the swapping part, when i change the first elements, the second operation affects the first operation too.

```
<div class="show-first">Vin Diesel</div> <!-- initial css property -> display:block; -->
<div class="show-first">Paul Walker</div> 

<div class="show-later">Gwen Stefani</div> <!-- initial css property -> display:none; -->
<div class="show-later">Christina Aguilera</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    function changeMe(){
        $(".show-first").switchClass("show-first", "show-later");
        $(".show-later").fadeIn("slow").switchClass("show-later", "show-first");
    }
    setInterval(changeMe,10000);
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3bA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $first = $(".show-first").hide(),
    $later = $(".show-later").fadeIn("slow");
$later.add($first).toggleClass("show-later show-first");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3bA/4/)